# How to send message to any number from app

Tags: ios, objective-c, sms

Actually i have implemented  app to phone call using Sinch. is there is any possibility to send message to any number from app like way2sms,etc.

Answer (score -1):

There are many services that will help you to build applications.

```
https://www.twilio.com/sms

https://www.twilio.com/sms/api

https://www.plivo.com/sms-api/
```

You can use some service like this and create SMS applications

Answer (score -2):

You can use the MFMessageComposeViewController:

More Information please refer the link:

http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-send-sms-text-message/

Comment: i know one can send message by using this. but How to make application like way2sms